# Отмечена по всему головному мозгу. Или во всем головном мозге?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

> Данная молекула отмечена **по всему головному мозгу** мыши.
>
> Данная молекула отмечена **во всем головном мозге** мыши.

Предложение должно означать, что молекула обнаружена во всех структурах мозга мыши (например, в коре, мозжечке, среднем мозге).
Какой предлог лучше выбрать и в чем различие между ними?

Comment: "Данная молекула обнаруживается во всех основных отделах головного мозга: мозжечке, коре, среднем мозге и др. Или: данная молекула обнаруживается повсюду в головном мозге: мозжечке, коре..." По всему мозгу и во всем мозге - очень общие фразы, не понятно как мозг коррелируется с молекулами.

Comment: @Буратино Можно привести еще вот такой пример на тему различия между этими предлогами: "Данная молекула участвует в физиологических процессах по всему организму / во всем организме".

Comment: Что-то "отмечена" не очень корректно использовано.

Comment: По - это чаще про поверхность, то что "на поверхности", а во - это "внутри". Однако, тут у вас два предлога "в" а потом "по/во". В этом случае наверное первый вариант предпочтительнее, чтобы не было два раза "внутри" - в процессах, процессах идущих по организму. То есть "по" относится не к "молекуле", а к "процессам". "В" дает больший акцент, о чем речь собственно идет, о молекуле, которая участвует в процессах, а далее более нейтрально "по...". А если два раза "В", то усложнение конструкции получится, что ли: молекула в процессах, а процессы в организма, а организм...

Comment: Но вообще физиологические процессы, они уже внутри или по организму, так что это излишество. Можно вообще это убрать, смысла "по всему организму" не добавляет. Можно заменить на: Данная молекула участвует во всех физиологических процессах. Внешних же физиологических процессов не бывает?

Comment: "В" при указании на место, а "по" при указании на распространение. Вектор разный.

Answer (score 1):

1. Одна молекула не может быть отмечена/обнаружена во всем мозге. Мозг состоит из мириадов молекул и не влезет в одну даже очень большую молекулу.
2. Фраза "Данное вещество отмечено/обнаружено во(по) всём(у) головном(у) мозге/у мыши." будет правильной только тогда, когда весь мозг мыши положат в ступку и тщательно разотрут до однородной массы (гомогенезируют). Затем определение вещества будет проводиться в этом гомогенате. А это не соответствует смыслу Вашего вопроса.
3. Если в паре предыдущих предложений не указано  в чем обнаружено данное вещество, то наиболее верным будет следующая конструкция. Данное вещество было отмечено в крови/плазме/нейронах/синапсах/.../ из всех структур головного мозга мыши.
4. В выводах можно указать:
   4.1. Если исследовали процесс - Данное вещество распространилось по всему головному мозгу мыши.
   4.2. Если исследовали конечный результат процесса - Данное вещество распространено во всем головном мозге мыши.

P.S. Извините, но в научной литературе принято читать точно, что написано, а не соображать, что подразумевал автор.